# Does Synchronized method synchronized if a Java method is invokded from PLSQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, synchronization, synchronized

I wondered that if a method is not invoked in a Java Thread but from a another thread or language, say plsql.

As far as I am concerned, plsql does not have thread ,but it has session, what if I hope that the method being called from plsql procedure can be synchronized.

My question is

1. Does the synchronized keyword still work fine
2. Does this calling create a java Thread
3. Does the synchronized keyword or other Java concurrency object (like Semaphore, conditionObject) is only working in a Java Thread?

The calling from pl/sql is like :

```
language java name 'xxx.xxx.xxx.Engine.execute(
                                java.lang.Integer,
                                java.lang.String,
                                java.sql.Timestamp,
                                java.sql.Timestamp,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.Long,
                                java.lang.String,
                        java.lang.Long )';
```

and the the execute method is a static method.

Comment: How can you invoke java code from plsql? Please share some code snippet. It will probably help to give you a good answer.

Comment: We cannot invoke java method directly instead we can call Java stored procedures from any PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package.

Comment: Hi M.Sharma, what do you mean "We cannot invoke java method directly " . Do you mean that the method "execute" is not a Java method, but a java stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the synchronized keyword still work fine

If the PL/SQL is actually calling into the Java then yes, it will call the `synchronized` keyword and block, etc..  However, I suspect that it is in a different JVM so the locks in your Java code are different from the ones being locked in PL/SQL.  If you look at your process list, you might see two JVM instances running.

One way to test this would be to debug your application and put a breakpoint in the `execute(...)` method.  If you stop at the breakpoint then you are in the same JVM, otherwise no.  Another thing to try is to print the value of `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()`.  If that is different from your Java client code then it's a different JVM.

> Does this calling create a java Thread

I suspect so.  I suspect that your ODBC call (is that what you are doing?) is a Remote Procedure Call to Oracle using some sort of network connection.  Then a thread inside of the Oracle server executes which hands off to the Java stuff.  I suspect that the Java is running in yet another thread.

To test the thread that is running you can use `Thread.currentThread().getId()`.  It might be the same randomly however so you'll also need to compare the `getName()` output shown above.

> Does the synchronized keyword or other Java concurrency object (like Semaphore, conditionObject) only is only working in a Java Thread?

I don't quite understand this question.  There is no way to execute Java code without being in a Java thread unless Oracle is interpreting the Java or something.

If you are asking if you are in the same Thread that made the Oracle database call then I doubt it.  See above.  If you are asking if it is the same JVM then I doubt it.  See above.